# How to create a relationship with a table which has a composite primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database, primary-key

I have two tables. I want to create a relationship between them. But the first table has two primary keys.

SpaDefinition Table:

BranchId,Id(PK),LanguageId(PK),Name

SpaPhotos Table:

BranchId, Id(PK),SpaDefinitionId,Data

The SpaPhotos table should have a relationship with SpaDefinition table.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: A table can only have one primary key. A primary key can however consist of two columns.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say . Id and LanguageId are together PK.

Comment: You can always `JOIN` the two tables on the `BranchId` column, but you will include all of the languages.  If you want to limit that further, you need to either add `LanguageId` to the `SpaPhotos` table, or explicitly specify its value in the query.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can create a foreign key in SpaPhotos that will reference SpaDefinition is to either:

1. Add LanguageId to SpaPhotos, or
2. Remove LanguageId from the Primary Key of SpaDefinition

A foreign key must contain ALL of the columns of the primary key of the table it is referencing.